# CKEditor 5 - allow and/or disallow specific tags

Tags: ckeditor5, typo3-12.x

CKEditor5 is the standard editor for TYPO3 12, and it brings a lot of features which looks promising in the first place. Unfortunatly there are also some backdrafts which are unacceptable to me and I'm searching for a solution:

If a user copies content from a Word-file or whatsoever, it's likely that in contains tags which are not allowed in the context of this specific content element, let's say a table.

As far as I understand CKE5 brings htmlSupport.allow and .disallow to solve this (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html/general-html-support.html#configuration), but I cannot bring this to work. Any configuration provided here seems to be simply ignored by the CKEditor.

I provide tag configuration (with or withoud additional classes, styles, ...) via htmlSupport.allow and I expect  CKEditor remove any other tags not whitelisted this way.

I provide tag configuration (with or withoud additional classes, styles, ...) via htmlSupport.disallow and I expect  CKEditor remove any tags blacklisted this way.